# Render Ajax html response in a new window

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to make an Ajax request to fetch a jsp page and render it in a new window.

Though the jsp got rendered in the new window, the click actions on the jsp are not functioning.

The jsp contains a few functions written in $(document).ready(function()..) related to click events, and I guess this is not getting invoked initially.

Below is the code snippet I use to fetch the jsp and render it in new window.

```
function openResponseInNewWindow(url) {
var nextWindow = window.open('', "example");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: "validFlag=true",
    dataType: "text/html",
    success: function (data) {
        nextWindow.document.write(data);
        nextWindow.opener = window;
        nextWindow.focus();
    }
});
```

}

Is there any possibility to make the jsp execute $(document).ready() so that click events get triggered, or any standard solution to render a jsp from ajax response which responds to click events?

Appreciate any help find a solution for this.

Comment: can you add some more details to the problem, like console error when you open nextwindow or code of jsp used inside nextwindow? So that we can help to answer your question.

Comment: There are no error on the console output in the nextwindow. The href on the new jsp seems to be not bind to click event.